# Can I loop through fullcalendar events after loading calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar-scheduler

My fullcalendar object has events loaded from a URL as seen below.  When an event on the calendar is clicked, I need to not only pass that event back to a function (which is built in), but I need to also find another event that is associated with the clicked event by a field called lesson_id).  Is there a way to loop through the events to find the other event with the same lesson_id?

```
       events: { 
                url: smurl + "&subCmd=sch",
                error: function () {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                },
                viewRender: function (view) {
                    try {
                        setTimeline(view); 
                    } catch (err) { }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found my answer.  It appears that .fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' [, idOrFilter ] ) returns an array of event objects held in memory.